# Prove the converse of "The sum of two odd consecutive numbers is a multiple of 4"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

The sum of two odd consecutive numbers is a multiple of 4. I've tried rewriting this as:
If $a$ and $b$ are two consecutive odd numbers, then $a+b=4p$, where $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to prove the converse of the statement, which I think is:

**If $z$ is a number of the form $4p,\ p\in\mathbb{N}$, then $z$ can be written as the sum of two odd consecutive numbers $a$ and $b$.**

**Proof.**

We write $4p$ as $2p-1+2p+1$, and we get $z=(2p-1)+(2p+1)$. If we denote $2p-1$ by $a$ and $2p+1$ by $b$, then we can notice that $a<b$ and $b-a=2$, so $a$ and $b$ are two odd consecutive numbers.

Is the above proof complete? I've recently started studying a proof writing book, and I want to make sure that I don't assume what need to be proved or other statements that may or may not be true.

Comment: Yes, it is correct!

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no mistake in your proof. Well done!

Comment: It's correct.  Good job!  You don't *need* to label $2p-1$ and $2p+1$ as $a$ and $b$ though.  It'd be enough to simply say "$2p-1$ and $2p+1$ are clearly odd numbers, and their difference is $2$ so they are consecutive odd numbers".

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

Another nice proof is as follow,
let $k = p-1$,
$$z = 4p = 4(k+1) \\ \implies z = 4k + 4 = (2k+1) + (2k+3) $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof looks great! Nice job on the converse: that's an important first step.

Note that I have edited your post so that instead of using $p$ as your variable (which is almost always used for primes), you are using $n$.

Comment: The OP has closed their account. May I ask why you are leaving them a note? They are very unlikely to ever read it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I am just trying to get it out of the "no answers" category because the question was answered in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why you were going back and answering all these rather old questions, and where you were getting them from!